# What's the left-hand side of a method invocation called?

Tags: oop, language-agnostic, nomenclature

Given the following line

```
cat.meow(10, x);
```

- "meow" is the "function" or "method" being called
- `10` is the "first argument"
- `x` is the "second argument"

**What is `cat` called?**

I'm dissatisfied with the answer, `cat` is called "the object". I want to say I've heard it called the "receiver", but I don't remember where I've heard that.

Considering both `10` and `x` can be objects, calling `cat` "the object" doesn't help me distinguish this component from the argument components.

This makes it difficult to discuss the various components that makeup a function call.

Comment: Not sure if correct but I would call it the variable.

Comment: using a literal on the left-hand side would not be a variable. It'd still be nice to be able to discuss the components of that type of expression as well. `[1,2,3].forEach(foo);`

Comment: In smalltalk and objective-c it would be receiver, as those languages you pass messages, not call functions.  In an OOP language cat would be an object as objects has methods, and you are calling a method.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting flagged as "opinion based". Calling `c` in `a.b(c)` and "argument" is not an _opinion_.

Comment: What about `callee`?

Comment: `i.call(it) // instance object`

Comment: @poida: Normally we call `meow` the callee.

Comment: Refusing to accept that an object is called an object is an *opinion*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called the “subject” following the [subject-verb-object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb%E2%80%93object) sentence structure that object-oriented programming mimics:

```
cat.meow(10, x);
|_||___||_____|
 |   |     |
 |   |     +--> object (the arguments list is a tuple object)
 |   |
 |   +--> verb (the verb is the method name with the dot)
 |
 +--> subject (quite self explanatory)
```

I should clarify that I call it the “subject” because it makes sense to me. However, there's no consensus on this nomenclature. Everyone has their own opinions on what it should be called.

Answer (score 1):

An object is an instance of a specific class. You can use it to say `cat` is an instance of class [put class name here], just like 10 is an instance of Integer.

Answer (score 0):

Normally we call that object. According to your logic, take it in this way

meow(self,10, x) - This is the actual function where self is an object like 10 and x

Same in this case - cat.meow(10,x)